# CertificateException when generateCertificate()

Tags: java, android, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am developing my android app. I am trying to generate the **X509Certificate** instance from my certificate file stream, but get `CertificateException` , here is my simple code:

```
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
...
public class CertMgr {
   //my certification file 'mycert.p12' located in my app internal storage
   File certFile = GET_CERT();

   X509Certificate cert = null;
   try {

      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(certFile);
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

      CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509"); 

      if(bis.available() > 0){
           //I got CertificateException here, see the stack trace
          cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis); //line nr 150
      }
   }catch(...)
      {...}
 ...
}
```

**stack trace:**

```
javax.security.cert.CertificateException: org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Exception: ASN.1 Sequence: mandatory value is missing at [4]
11-11 17:30:20.731: W/System.err(11529):    at javax.security.cert.X509Certificate.getInstance(X509Certificate.java:94)
11-11 17:30:20.731: W/System.err(11529):    at javax.security.cert.X509Certificate.getInstance(X509Certificate.java:213)
11-11 17:30:20.731: W/System.err(11529):    at com.my.app.CertMgr.getCert(CertMgr.java:150)
```

Could someone please explain to me why I get this exception?

**P.S.:** Here are the classes I am using from Android SDK [X509Certificate](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) , [CertificateFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html)

If you are curious about why I am doing this, the reason is that I want my app to be able to install the certificate(*mycert.p12*) by the following code (if above code is working properly):

```
Intent installIntent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();

installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, cert.getEncoded());
installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, MY_CERT);
startActivityForResult(installIntent, INSTALL_KEYCHAIN_CODE);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to read a PKCS#12 data structure as it was a X509 certificate. The [PKCS#12](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs12-personal-information-exchange-syntax-standard.htm) standard specifies a data structure which can bundle multiple certificates and private keys, optionally protected by a password.

In order to read the PKCS#12 data you need to load it with a [KeyStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html). This code snippet show how list all entries of the PCKS#12 file:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
File p12File = GET_CERT();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(p12File);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
keyStore.load(bis, password.toCharArray()); // password is the PKCS#12 password. If there is no password, just pass null
Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();
    /* Do something with the keystore entry */
}
```

KeyStore entries can be private key, with or without an associated certificate chain (i.e. a sequence of certificate from the root certificate to the certificate corresponding to the private key), or a trusted certificate. You can determine the entry type by the `KeyStore.isKeyEntry` and `KeyStore.isCertificateEntry` methods.

According to the KeyChain intent you gave, it seems you want to add a new trusted Root CA certificate in the key chain. Therefore I think you should list the certificate entries of the PKCS#12 file.

**EDIT (12th nov 2013)**

How to get a trusted certificate from the keystore:

```
String alias = aliases.nextElement();
if (keyStore.isCertificateEntry(alias)) { // keep only trusted cert entries
    Certificate caCert = keyStore.getCertificate(alias)
    byte[] extraCertificate = caCert.getEncoded();
    Intent installIntent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
    installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, extraCertificate);
    installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, MY_CERT);
    startActivityForResult(installIntent, INSTALL_KEYCHAIN_CODE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I want to install a new CA certificate. I have the file like my code showed. This file is just a certificate, I have also installed the file manually without any problem, here I just do it programmatically. I am a bit confused with your answer, since I think the file is just a certificate file because I have installed it manually for testing purpose, but seems you mean this file (mycert.p12) is a keystore which could contain multiple certificates?

Comment: I just was making assumptions. p12 extension is used for PKCS#12 files and the exception you got seems to be caused by an invalid file format. Another possible cause is the file encoding: X.509 certificate factory only support DER (bianry) encoding. If your file encoding is PEM (base64) you should convert it. If possible, you should try to open/display the file with OpenSSL. IMHO the best way to determine the file type/format.

Comment: Hi, jcs, you are right, after using your code, I got the aliases. How can I install the certificate programmatically then?

Comment: Thanks, jcs, I will try your updated code & accept your answer,by the way, I am a bit confused about whether I should install the keystore or only install the certificate in the keystore ? (In my keystore there is one key entry & a certificate entry). In practice what is the difference? For example, the following link 1st installed the keystore after which installed the certificate : http://nelenkov.blogspot.fi/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html

Comment: As far as I know (but I do not have much experience with android KeyChain) android KeyChain contains two kinds of objects: private keys  with a certificate chain and trustworthy CA certificate. Installing the keystore is when you want to inject a  private key and its certificate chain into the KeyChain. If you just want to add a trusted certificate, you have to add the certificate and not the keystore. In the code snippet the KeyStore is actually only used to unwrap the certificate contained in the PKCS#12 file.