# Why the method generateCertificate return a CertificateException when I trying to add my SSL certificate?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore

I'm trying to accept my SSL certificate for API tests.
For that, I exported my certificate with IE (with the second option : x.509 binary encod base 64 (*.cer)
I added it in the keystore with this command line :

```
 keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore "C:\Program
 Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -alias "certificatealias"
```

To list keystore and check if I have my certificate entry, I use this command line :

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Program
     Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\security\cacerts"  > java_cacerts.txt
```

I have my certificate entry inside :

> Nom d'alias : certificatealias Date de création : 6 déc. 2016 Type
>   d'entrée : trustedCertEntry
>
> Propriétaire : CN=Test, O=Test Emetteur :
>   CN=Test, O=Test Numéro de série : XXXX
>   Valide du : xxx au : xxxx
>
> Empreintes du certificat :      MD5: Xxxxxx     SHA1 :xxxx      SHA256 :
>   XXXX
>
> Nom de l'algorithme de signature : SHA256withRSA     Version : 3

In my code, I have :

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("certificate.jks");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(bis, "changeit".toCharArray());

Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();
    System.out.println("alias: " + alias);
    System.out.println("bis.available: " +bis.available());
    System.out.println("bis: "+ bis.toString());

    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
    KeyStore.Entry newEntry = new KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry(x509);
    ks.setEntry("certificatealias", newEntry, null);
}
```

I received an error :

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate:
>   java.io.IOException: Empty input

In my console I have :

> alias: certificatealias
>
> bis.available: 0
>   bis: java.io.BufferedInputStream@8xx9d4

The error is on `cf.generateCertificate(bis)`.

Why I have this error? cf and bis are not null or empty...

I saw it can be the keystore type that can be wrong (see the post [3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910593/certificateexception-when-generatecertificate)). `KeyStore.getDefaultType()` return JKS. That should be good, isn't ? 
I've checked with the command line :
`keytool -list -keystore <keystore_location>` I've the type :

> Type de fichier de clés : JKS
>
> Fournisseur de fichier de clés : SUN

Any hint will be very helpful!

Comment: You have your keystore loaded in your `bis` input stream. You can't use that create a certificate out of it, because it is the whole keystore. If you need to get the certificate object and add it to your keystore, you should load the certificate using input stream (like you did for the keystore), and feed that input stream to the `generateCertificate` method. You could use input stream like `FileInputStream` to load the certificate.

Comment: thanks for your help. I added these lines : `FileInputStream certificate = new FileInputStream("certificate.cer");
  BufferedInputStream bis2 = new BufferedInputStream(certificate);` and corrected the line to    cf.generateCertificate(bis2);` However, I get another error  `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: You may not be having the complete certificate chain in your truststore.

Comment: When I print the `cf.generateCertificate(bis2)` I have : `cert: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Test, O=Test
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = XX

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: XX (too long)
  public exponent: xx
  Validity: [From: X 
               To: X
  Issuer: CN=Test, O=Test
  SerialNumber: [ xx]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature: XX (too long)
] '

Comment: Looks like it is a test certificate, you should the whole chain to your cacert keystore to make it work. If you are using dynamic approach of creating the truststore with the certificates that are needed to make the connection, you need to create a custom SSLSocketFactory, you can refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875264/fetch-ssl-certificate-from-local-store-using-java-into-sslcontext-object/40875974#40875974.

And before your call, you could do 

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

Comment: it's not a test but a custom certificate. I put test and x everywhere because we are limited in characters in comment :). I'm reading the post you sent me, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130026/discussion-between-always-a-rookie-to-learn-and-fanny-v).